# Knockout: How to hide a <tr> having applied "with" knockout binding to it

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table. I have applied a `with binding` on the `<tr>` element and also want to apply a `visible` attribute to it.

html:

```
<table>
    <tr data-bind="with: names">
        <td>
            First Name:
            <span data-bind="text: first" />       
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

js:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
     this.names = {
            first:  "John",
            isVisible: false
     };
   };

   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I want to write something like `<tr data-bind="with: names, visible: isVisible">` but knockout does not allow this syntax.

Hiding the `<td>` element like `<td data-bind="visible: isVisible">` is not an option.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/43/

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will have `names` context only inside tr you can use `name.IsVisible` in tr's `data-bind`:

```
<table>
    <tr data-bind="with: names, visible: names.isVisible">
        <td>
            First Name:
            <span data-bind="text: first" />       
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/44/